# Automatically detect column from 1-5 by a given number

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm writing small JavaScript game with the 5x5 table. Every field in the table have it's own ID (from 1 to 25). I already have a function *put(id)* that checks in what row should a number be written:

```
if (id > 0 && id <= 5)
     // write to first row
...
```

What would be the best way to do same check for columns but without writing clause for every case (if id is 3 write to third column / if it's 20 write to first column etc.) ? This is only thing I made up in my mind to this moment (make two element array for every field, first for row and second for column and use that number for argument in second function):

```
[
[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], // [row, column]
[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4],
...
]
```

Is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use Remainder operator (%) this way:

```
if (id % 5 === 1) { // 1st column }
if (id % 5 === 2) { // 2nd column }
if (id % 5 === 3) { // 3rd column }
if (id % 5 === 4) { // 4th column }
if (id % 5 === 0) { // 5th column }
```

You can find out how it works here: [Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_%28%29)

Comment: That was the first I thought, but I can't use it for all IDs (for example 23, 14, 18)...

Comment: why not? why are these number different from the rest?

Comment: @Ni. Because I know what's the column then, but I still have to do multiple loop checking - both for rows and columns. With my approach I can just write function like this add(id) and in function get row and column easily (table[id][0] for row and table[id][1] for column). I'm looking for fastest aproach because I'll need AI later too.

Comment: @Nikola, your approach is one of the fastest, my way is cleaner but if your priority is speed then you'd better keep it as an [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) and instead of table[id][0] use column[id] and row[id], it's faster and cleaner then you did.